# Defination of RAT?

Tags: rat

I've just noticed that different sites define RAT differently. Which one should be used?

Remote Access Tool
https://www.cybersecurity-review.com/tag/rat/

Remote Access Trojan
https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/RAT-remote-access-Trojan

Remote Administration Tool
https://www.mcafee.com/blogs/consumer/what-is-rat/

When was `RAT` term has been introduced?

If I recalled correctly, it was known just as `trojan` last time.

The reason I'm asking this is it might be asked in Security exam.

Comment: All those 3 mean more or less the same thing from a security standpoint. On an exam I would think that knowing what it is/does (so you can explain it) is way more important than knowing which one of the correct-ish names to blurt out.